# Do input tensors and output tensors have to match in order to have successful Object Detection?

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, torchvision

I trained a YOLOv8 model on custom data and it works well when I use the YOLOv8 detection functionality however I want to run it on an Android (or even iOS device at this point).  I exported it to torchscript and that's where I have hit a wall.  I wrote an Android app using the model from the optimized for mobile torchscript api.  There is a negligible size difference between the .pt and .ptl file so I'm not sure if it really optimized.

The input tensor size from the camera is Tensor([1, 3, 1024, 1024], dtype=torch.float32),
the output tensor is Tensor([1, 31, 21504], dtype=torch.float32).

Could that be why the detections aren't working properly due to a shape mismatch error?  The debug console really doesn't show any mismatch errors though.  In addition I ran into this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 37822, Size: 27.  I have 27 classes in the model.  I did a tutorial on youtube so I can't take credit for all the code but here is the partial code snippet (I posted the code minus the imports).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

    PreviewView previewView;

    TextView textView;

    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 101;

    List<String> classes;

    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"android.permission.CAMERA"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        previewView = findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.result_text);

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
        }

        classes = LoadClasses("labels.txt");
        LoadTorchModule("model.ptl");
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                startCamera(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // Errors
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        for (String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    void startCamera(@NotNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetResolution(new Size(1024, 1024)).setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build();

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
            @Override
            public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                int rotation = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
                analyzeImage(image, rotation);
                image.close();
            }
        });

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis);
    }

    Module module;

    void LoadTorchModule(String fileName) {
        File modelFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), fileName);
        try {
            if (!modelFile.exists()) {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(fileName);
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(modelFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            }
            module = LiteModuleLoader.load(modelFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OptIn(markerClass = ExperimentalGetImage.class) void analyzeImage(ImageProxy image, int rotation) {
        try {
            Tensor inputTensor = TensorImageUtils.imageYUV420CenterCropToFloat32Tensor(image.getImage(), rotation, 1024, 1024, TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_MEAN_RGB, TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_STD_RGB);
            Tensor outputTensor = module.forward(IValue.from(inputTensor)).toTensor();

            Log.v("ZackTensor", inputTensor.toString());
            Log.v("ZackTensor", outputTensor.toString());
            float[] scores = outputTensor.getDataAsFloatArray();
            float maxScore = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
            Log.v("ZackTensor", String.valueOf(maxScore));
            int maxScoreIdx = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                if (scores[i] > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = scores[i];
                    maxScoreIdx = i;
                }
            }
            String classResult = classes.get(maxScoreIdx);

            Log.v("ZackTensor", "Detected - " + classResult);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(classResult);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    List<String> LoadClasses(String fileName) {
        List<String> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(fileName)));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                classes.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return classes;
    }
}
```

I tried re-exporting the model with no luck.  I tried reshaping the incoming image but either I didn't do it properly or it didn't work.  I've done loads of Googling and on Stackoverflow but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a torchlite format within the available YOLOv8 export formats: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/export/#export-formats. Make sure the exported model does the NMS part, otherwise, you need to write it manually, like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76176401/how-to-interpret-output-tensor-from-yolov8-web-model/76378292#76378292